# Good way to prevent duplicated event handle

Tags: java, android, architecture, software-design

I have a common problem since the first day I start coding: avoid handling an event (button click,..) multiple times. Most of the time, I come up with a simple solution (which add a boolean flag to check) like this:

```
private boolean isProcessingClick = false;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    onLoginButtonClick();
}

private void onLoginButtonClick() {
    if (isProcessingClick) 
        return;
    isProcessingClick = true;

    // Do something..
    // Update some UIs..

    isProcessingClick = false;
}
```

This worked fine. But as the class go bigger with more features & events everything started going wrong. We need to create **too many boolean flags** which doesn't mean anything about the business and **should not be a field of this class**.

Does anyone has better solution for this?

Comment: Boolean flags are states, therefore you probably want to use state-machine architecture, or viewmodel based approach

Comment: Thank you for replying me @Steyrix , do you have any example?

Comment: If you are OK with using state-machines (in which case the button click will cause you to change state of the whole view, depending on current state), you probably want to use **redux**. Unfortunately I have lost articles, that I found very useful in past. Maybe this one will be interesting for you https://jayrambhia.com/blog/android-redux-intro

Answer (score 1):

The restriction can be supported with a wrapper (if you need to protect click of each button independently).

```java
class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final View.OnClickListener internal;
    private final AtomicBoolean isProcessingClick = new AtomicBoolean();

    public MyOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener internal) {
        this.internal = internal;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            boolean noProcessing = this.isProcessingClick.compareAndSet(false, true);
            if(noProcessing) {
                internal.onClick(v);
            } else {
                // it's good to show some alert for the user here
            }
        } finally {
            isProcessingClick.set(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not android developer so `AtomicBoolean` was used in case that 'onClick' could be invoked by different threads.

Comment: This is quite good solution, but have a restriction that cannot use a **single** listener instance for multiple buttons (let activity/fragment extends `View.OnClickListener` then set with `this`)

Comment: Yeah, I've got it,
what I suggested is to use separate wrapper for each button